# How to implement Text to Speech in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, text-to-speech

I'm trying to have a simple webpage where once I hover over the div tag, it will start reading the text, and if I move away, it will pause. The thing is I do not know how to implement the text to speech features. The ones I tried didn't work.

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import "./Subject1.css";

function Subject1() {
  const subject1_topic =  useRef(null)
  const speak = () => {
    
  }
  const dontspeak = () => {
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="subject1">
      <div className="subject1_title">Periodic Table:</div>
      <div className="subject1_topic" ref={subject1_topic} onMouseEnter={() => speak()} onMouseLeave={() => dontspeak()}>
        The periodic table, also known as the periodic table of elements, is a
        tabular display of the chemical elements, which are arranged by atomic
        number, electron configuration, and recurring chemical properties.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Subject1;
```

So basically I need it to read out loud when I'm hovering over subject_topic div.

Comment: You could use the web speech API which most browsers support https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#tts-section

Comment: Ok , will check it out , thanks

Comment: @Tinjar did it work for you?

Comment: @SritejaSugoor nope, but didnt try too hard. Took the easy way out of recording audio manually and playing audio on mouse entry.